# How to configure static files in Django app for Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed a django app to heroku, using "git push heroku master". It works fine but i have problem with static files. I can't configure it. What i have to do to get it started? Can you help me guys?

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
```

base.html

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/base.css" %}' />
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.views import (login_view, register_view, logout_view)
from timetable.views import home
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^timetable/', include("timetable.urls", namespace='timetable')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', register_view, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^$', home, name='controler'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Did you read the nicely detailed instructions about [Django and Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) in the Heroku documentation?

Comment: Well, then you should at least show the relevant bits of your configuration to show you have enabled whitenoise.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say you've read and followed that documentation, but haven't installed Whitenoise. Why not? Go back and read that doc again, and follow what it says to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from django.contrib import admin
# all other necessary imports

admin.autodiscover()
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname((__file__))

urlpatterns = [
    # all my url() patterns
]

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
         )
```